# RHEL 6 TFTP server on VMware vSphere 5 not accepting files from remote clients

Tags: centos, redhat, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, tftp

I can put a file successfully from localhost. If I try from another host the client connects and the file is created on the server, but it is empty. The transfer then times out a little later.

On the client I can run one of the following with the same result:

```
tftp <server> -c put install.log
tftp <server> -c put install.log install.log
tftp <server> -c put install.log /install.log
```

SELinux is in permissive mode, and IPtables is currently off.

Contents of /etc/xinetd.d/tftpd:

```
service tftp
{
    socket_type             = dgram
    protocol                = udp
    wait                    = yes
    user                    = root
    server                  = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args             = -v -c -s /var/lib/tftpboot
    disable                 = no
    per_source              = 11
    cps                     = 100 2
    flags                   = IPv4
}
```

/tftproot has got 777 permissions.

In /var/log/messages I get:

```
Mar 21 17:10:30 <hostname> in.tftpd[29093]: WRQ from <client_ip> filename install.log
Mar 21 17:10:35 <hostname> in.tftpd[29093]: WRQ from <client_ip> filename install.log
Mar 21 17:10:40 <hostname> in.tftpd[29093]: WRQ from <client_ip> filename install.log
Mar 21 17:10:45 <hostname> in.tftpd[29093]: WRQ from <client_ip> filename install.log
Mar 21 17:10:50 <hostname> in.tftpd[29093]: WRQ from <client_ip> filename install.log
```

Been banging my head against this brick wall all afternoon. Someone please put me out of my misery. I know it will be something really stupid :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem

It was the VMware NIC type. I was using the VNXNET3, once I changed to E1000 everythings works as expected. Apparently, the problem still exists in vSphere 5.

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/215456

Answer (score 1):

I think this is MTU/fragmentation problem. Small packets between client and servers travel without problem, so server know filename. Large is blocked somewhere.

You sholud use `-B max-block-size` flag with minimum block size (512) for server and if this fix the problem then also try bigger one (~1460 is good one for Ethernet with 1500 MTU, but if you have IPSec/VPN between client and server then ~1350 may be better).

Comment: If this not the answer then check firewall on client side - if you block UDP from server to client result will be probably same - `track` option in client can help.

Comment: Interesting, I like solutions that are somebody else's problem :) Sadly I work in a heavily Silo'ed environment - 'aint no DevOps here :-(

Comment: No such joy there. I set the block size to 512 and get exactly the same result. The Windows people will start laughing at me soon

Comment: @chriscowley Could you tell more detail of network between client and server? Is there NAT somewhere? Firewall? (tftp is not [firewall-friendly](http://www.winagents.com/en/solutions/tftp-over-firewall.php) )
Could you try add `--port-range 69:69` option to tftpd config?

Comment: The TFTP server is VM on an ESXi 4.1 server, connected to a standard vSphere vSwitch. This is in turn connected to a Cisco 3560, which is currently the device we are trying to backup.

Comment: Wireshark output for [server](https://owncloud.chriscowley.me.uk/public.php?service=files&file=%2Fchris%2Ffiles%2Fobs-shared%2FUCaaS-Fr%2Fserver-SameHost.pcap) and [client](https://owncloud.chriscowley.me.uk/public.php?service=files&file=%2Fchris%2Ffiles%2Fobs-shared%2FUCaaS-Fr%2Fclient-SameHost.pcap)

Comment: @chriscowley Strange. Looks like server not event try to reply :\ Are you sure about just ACCEPT in iptables?

Answer (score 0):

In EL6, the default tftp directory changed from `/tftpboot` to `/var/lib/tftpboot`.

Make sure you have a file in the destination directory with 666 permissions on the file.

Comment: He is using the `-c` option, so the existence of the file is not required.

Comment: I'm aware of that move and I am working with /var/lib/tftpboot